# What is the meaning of segment in MTRs?

Tags: military, usa, terminology, aeronautical-charts

Military Training Routes (MTRs) with no segment above 1,500' AGL shall be identified by four number characters (IR1206/VR1207)

MTRs that include one or more segments above 1,500' AGL shall be identified  with three number characters (IR206/VR207).

---

What is the meaning of **segment** in MTRs?

What is the **difference** between three and four?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **route** is how you go from place to place.  A **segment** is a portion of your route which is characterized by a consistent course/altitude.

A route may have one segment, or many.  An MTR is a Military Training **Route**.  If no portions of the route exceed 1,500 AGL, then it is given a four-digit identifier.

I'm pretty sure that the three-digit / four-digit decision was arbitrary, but I'm ready to be educated.

[image]